# How to print the prediction interval (upper and lower bound) in pycaret-ts-alpha

Tags: python, time-series, pycaret, multivariate-time-series

I want to know how to determine the prediction interval (upper and lower bound) in  pycaret-ts-alpha.

I am only trying to forecast one point value, but I need to determine it's upper and lower bound.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In predict_model()
return_pred_int: bool, default = False
When set to True, it returns lower bound and upper bound prediction interval, in addition to the point prediction.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend migrating to the newly released pycaret 3.0.0rc package as it has an updated version of the time series module that is now full integrated with all other modules in PyCaret (regression, classification, anomaly, etc.)